# How to get image from html document retrieved with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I want to get the first image of an external webpage and then display it. I use a XMLHttpRequest to get the document from the webpage, then I search for the first image in that document then display it. But no image shows up. This is for a chrome app, not a web page/website. Here is my javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://ab.reddit.com/', true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var ext_doc = this.response;
  var img_src = ext_doc.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var img_html = document.querySelector('#TestImage2');
  img_html.src = img_src.src;
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Try logging `img_src` to see what (if anything) you get.

Comment: I cannot check what is logged to the console because I am on a school administrated Chromebook, and that functionality is blocked.

Comment: Client-side web scraping is not possible [due to security issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31626877/6941627). You'll have to go server-side with this. You can use PhantomJS for example, but there's a lot more alternatives.

Comment: I was able to retrieve a direct image this way though, and I am able to parse  the document into a string and display the html

Comment: Well right now you have a typo, `scr` instead of `src`. Also, you should warn your school sysadmins that they forgot to lock down installing unpacked extensions..

Comment: I have fixed the typo but no image shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I cannot directly set the image src to the retrieved url src of the external image from the external html document. I have to send another XMLHttpRequest for the newly found image scr url and retrieve it as a blob. Then set the image src to `window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response)`. `this.response` being the image blob. I am not quite sure why it has to be done this way, probably for some security reason. I also put this into its own function. The `pgURL` parameter is the url of the web page for images to be retrieved. `index` is the index of the image wanted in the list of all the images on the web page. And `display` is the image html element to be changed.

```
function getImage(pgURL, index, display)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', pgURL, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'document';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var doc = this.response;
    var img_src = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")[index];
    var src = img_src.src;
    //Have to make a new XMLHttpRequest for the image found because img sources cannot be directly set
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open('GET',src);
    xhr2.responseType = 'blob'; //Must make blob object of retrieved image
    xhr2.onload = function(e){
        display.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response); //Finally set the src for the image
    };
    xhr2.send();

  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

REMINDER! This is for a chrome app, not a website.

Comment: Oh, right, Chrome App - I missed that the first time I read your question. Here's a full [documentation article](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external) on the topic! (spoiler: it presents the very same solution)