# Scraping page for links

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'd like to use javascript to scrape a webpage and collect all links ending in .jpg into an array. Ideally, it would do this every five minutes. Is this possible in a client-side language like Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use client-side JS? You can use server-side JS a la node.js. Check out @jeznag's answer below.

Comment: I was just hoping to accomplish this without having to download and install anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser-based client-side scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581051/browser-based-client-side-scraping)

Answer (score 2):

Why does it need to be javascript? BTW JS isn't just a client side language. You can use Node JS e.g. https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis

```
osmosis
.get('www.craigslist.org/about/sites')
.find('a[href*="jpg"]')
```