# Python regex error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The following regex is supposed to match any `:text:` that's preceeded by `start-of-string`, `whitespace` or `:`, and succeeded by `end-of-string`, `whitespace` or `:` (Along with a few extra rules)

I'm not great at regex but I've come up with the desired solution in regexr.com:

```regex
(?<=\s|:|^)(:[^\s|:]+:)(?=\s|:|$)
```

```regex
:match1::match2: :match3:
:match4:
000:matchNot:
:matchNot:000
:match Not:
```

Result: `:match1:`, `:match2:`, `:match3:`, `:match4:`

But on Python 3 this raises an error.

```py
re.search("(?<=\s|:|^)(:[^\s|:]+:)(?=\s|:|$)", txt)
```

**re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern**

Anyone know a good workaround for this issue? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you use `(?<![^\s:]):[^\s:]+:(?![^\s:])` and not `(?:^|(?<=[\s:]))(:[^\s:]+:)(?=[\s:]|$)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex Engine - "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089922/python-regex-engine-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python, you may use this work-around to avoid this error:

```
(?:^|(?<=[\s:]))(:[^\s:]+:)(?=[\s:]|$)
```

Anchors `^` and `$` are zero-width matchers anyway.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oPLg8a/2)

Answer (score 13):

Possibly the easiest solution would be to use the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which supports infinite lookbehinds:

```
import regex as re

data = """:match1::match2: :match3:
:match4:
000:matchNot:
:matchNot:000
:match Not:"""

for match in re.finditer("(?<=\s|:|^)(:[^\s|:]+:)(?=\s|:|$)", data):
    print(match.group(0))
```

This yields

```
:match1:
:match2:
:match3:
:match4:
```

Comment: This is definitely easier than splitting up look-behinds. If you can use a different library, of course.

Comment: This just saved me from my hell-long pattern to break :)

Comment: I was using pandas `str.findall` and it apparently uses `re` under the bonnet. Had to use `regex` with `.apply` instead, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install `regex`:

```
$ pip3 install regex
```

then, we'd write some expression and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` the patterns that we wouldn't want to be there:

```
import regex as re

expression = r'(?:^\d+:[^:\r\n]+:$|^:[^:\r\n]+:\d+$|^(?!.*:\b\S+\b:).*$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|:[a-z0-9]+:'
string = '''
:match1::match2: :match3:
:match4:
000:matchNot:
:matchNot:000
:match Not:

'''

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[':match1:', ':match2:', ':match3:', ':match4:']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/NI4lgJ/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/NI4lgJ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]