# I'm unable to write regular expression for capturing mount options from fstab

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I'm trying capture mount options in fstab config with python regex module for /tmp LV.

This is how the config looks like:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_home    /home          ext4    nosuid,nodev        1 2
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_opt     /opt           ext4    nosuid,nodev        1 2
#/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_tmp     /tmp           ext4    nosuid,noexec       1 2
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_tmp     /tmp           ext4    nosuid,nodev        1 2
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_var     /var           ext4    nosuid,nodev        1 2
```

So I need to capture only options **"nosuid,nodev"** from this line:
`/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_tmp     /tmp           ext4    nosuid,nodev        1 2`

I tried this:
`(?<=\s+\/tmp\s+ext4\s+)(\,|[a-z])+(?=\s+[0-9])`

But it also caputures commented line.
Even worse python re module can't run this regex expression because of this problem with lookbehind **The contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length, meaning that abc or a|b are allowed, but a* and a{3,4} are not.**
-source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

If I try to run it with current regex this error will popup
`look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

How should I construct regex expression for this?

### Very important, I can't use any other module than re!

I visited a few sites such as:
[Python regex error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310184/python-regex-error-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern)
[Python Regex Engine - "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089922/python-regex-engine-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern-error)

But I wasn't able to construct anything that would work for my kind of problem.

Comment: Could you solve this by looping over each line, and checking `line.startswith('#')` to ignore commented lines?

Comment: @NickODell Unfortunately not, I need to match it on place with single regex without any additional code.

Comment: Why do you **need** to use a regular expression when it's absolutely not necessary for the required functionality. Homework perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a regex like this?

```
^[^\s#]+\s+/tmp\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

No lookaround, matches only `/tmp`, and captures the options into group 1. Avoids matching the commented line by saying that the first field may contain any character which is not whitespace or `#`.

https://regex101.com/r/rK8rLA/1

Answer (score 0):

Given the required functionality and no reasonable explanation for the need to use *re* then it's as simple as:

```
with open('/etc/fstab') as fstab:
    for line in fstab:
        fs_spec, _, _, fs_mntops, *_ = line.split()
        if not fs_spec.startswith('#'):
            print(fs_mntops)
```