# Is there any library of reactJS to scrap webpages ? I want some specific data from website in my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping

I tried using nodejs its working but I want to do using reactJS only without node js, please let me know if any available there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't be able to use the browser of your clients to scrape content from other websites using JavaScript because of a security measure called [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
visit this post:
[browser-based-client-side-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581051/browser-based-client-side-scraping)

Comment: Thanks @reza ghorbani  but do you have any alternative solution for that?

Comment: I guess the only way is using server side languages

Comment: Yes, you are right.