# How to get JSON data from an external window in javaScript(different domains)

Tags: javascript, cors, window, sapui5

I have opened an external window in SAPUI5 app that returns a simple json. It runs an MII transaction in SAPMII and returns a JSON that shows in the external window.
[image: This is the json from external window]

How can I capture this json from the external window and show it in the console of the main window. (I need the json to show a response to the user that the server is running good)

Thanks.

I tried looking into js window api but did not get anything useful. Using xttp/ajax returns CORS error but is there a way to solve it too? The error I get are these 2.
[image]

This is the ajax call,,I have set crossDomain as true.

```
onCheckServer: function () {
        console.log("Toast: Checking server");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"https://vchgmesd251.na.int.grp:50001/XMII/Runner?Transaction=DEVTest/ServerCheck/Transaction/serverCheckTest&OutputParameter=MessageSend&content-type=text/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am running this app from my local pc.

Comment: You can't read the JSON text from the other window if it's cross domain, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581051/browser-based-client-side-scraping). And you can't do it with ajax, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i). If you need this information, you'll have to have your *server* (or a non-browser process on your PC) request the cross-domain page and read the text, and then send it to your page (if you still need it in a page).